# How to show warning if unknown prop is passed in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Suppose my react component should be called like this

```
<comp propA='a' />
```

and i want to check using proptypes if someone says

```
<comp propA='a' propB='a' />
```

i should get a warning saying that propB can not be accepted

**I DONT WANT TO USE A CUSTOM PROP TYPE IMPLEMENTATION** just want to know if this propblem is already tackled?

Comment: may i ask what is the use case?

Comment: mostly not writing redundant code, i am begining with react and i got curious as i only found validations regarding values in props not keys

Comment: You want to know (at run-time) if someone passed another prop?

Comment: yes without writing a custom proptype validator

Comment: tell us more about your use case.

Comment: whats wrong with `const {propA} = this.props`? this way you are ignoring any other prop passed. or am i missing your goal here

Comment: no .. just want to avoid the redundant code , dev should know that he can remove `propB='b'` part from the code that is what i want to achieve

Comment: `PropTypes` won't let you do it out of the box as far as i know. and it makes sense as they check individual prop and not prop collection.

Comment: yes got that in an answer, with the link to issue as well. I think thats it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prop-types package does not currently support this. Here is an open issue requesting it: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/issues/11.

It looks like https://github.com/airbnb/prop-types does support this (I know you said you don't want a custom prop type implementation) with forbidExtraProps.

Another option is using Typescript, which would enforce this at compile time rather than runtime.

Comment: this  gives me what i wanted , btw how will typescript help. Sorry but i only know that you can have typescript to allow for types but how will it check the keys in prop object ?

Comment: with an `interface` declaration i think

Comment: oh i see, you mean define the interface to be implemented by props and wherever props is required as parameter , use that interface

Comment: but will TS be able to understand this syntax `<comp propA='a' propB='a' />` to know that function is called with what params ?

Comment: Yep, here's a quick codesandbox that illustrates: https://codesandbox.io/s/9y1pmlo05p. Notice that the IDE is showing me `Property 'c' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ChildCompProps'.`. Typescript docs has a quick little section on using it with React as well: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing [Flow](https://flow.org/) addresses. Flow is commonly used with React code (see [this part of the documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/)).

---

You've said you don't want to do it yourself (good!) but just in case someone else ends up here who does: It's easy enough to check an object for properties you don't want in the constructor (or the function, if it's an SFC):

```
if (Object.keys(props).some(prop => prop !== "propA")) {
    throw new Error(prop + " is not a valid property for <component name>");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input , but i am just looking for a way in react props i can manually validate props with custom prop type anyway

Comment: @ashishsingh - I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i am not asking how will i do it, i wanted to know if prop-types library allow me to do this thing directly

Comment: @Sagivb.g - See the link. Sure looks like they're specifying more than one property.

Answer (score 0):

prop-types-exact may be a helpful module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types-exact